# Android showcaseview trying to make circle smaller

Tags: android, showcaseview

I tried to find some information how to do that but nothing works for me so far.

When I try to do that:
new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity(), true)

Outer 2 glowing circle is gone and other two circles lose their colors. Only button remains to have the proper color.

Dimens.xml

```
<dimen name="showcase_radius">40dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_inner">44dp</dimen>
<dimen name="showcase_radius_outer">48dp</dimen>
```

Styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomShowcaseTheme">
        <item name="sv_backgroundColor">#CC000000</item>
        <item name="sv_buttonText">Close</item>
        <item name="sv_tintButtonColor">true</item>
        <item name="sv_titleTextAppearance">@style/CustomTitle</item>
        <item name="sv_detailTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTitle" parent="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>

<style name="TextAppearance.ShowcaseView.Detail" parent="android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Example - as you can see there is no default color and outer circles are gone:

[image]

With the same settings but with new ShowcaseView.Builder(getActivity()) the innter circle get smaller but other ones do not follow it but they stay where they were.
[image]

Is there any solution to make them all get smaller but look exactly the same as default circles?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found out a "solution" that worked for me, but maybe is not the correct way to do it. It's a bit late for the author but maybe it still can be helpful for anyone else.

1. That glowing circle is an image called **cling_bleached.png**. Find it (drawable-xhdpi folder) and **resize it** (from 800x800 to 400x400)
2. Set **showcase_radius to 47** (half the original 94). Don't change the other two radius.
3. **Don't use true** in ShowcaseView.Builder.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **solution** I use.

I do prefer it because it **does not modify the original sources** of the *ShowcaseView*.

But it uses **reflection**.

1. First set any desired value into your resources xml like

   ```
   <dimen name="sv_radius">40dp</dimen>
   ```
2. Use this method to create an instance of the ShowcaseView.Builder

   ```
       private ShowcaseView.Builder createShowcaseViewBuilder() {

           ShowcaseView.Builder showcaseViewBuilder = new ShowcaseView.Builder(activity, true)
                   /**
                    * set theme
                    */
                   .setStyle(R.style.ShowcaseTheme4);
           /**
            * Load the new radius from resource xml
            */
           float radius = activity.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.sv_radius);

           try {
               Field showcaseViewField = ShowcaseView.Builder.class.getDeclaredField("showcaseView");
               showcaseViewField.setAccessible(true);
               Object showcaseViewObject = showcaseViewField.get(showcaseViewBuilder);
               Field showcaseDrawerField = ShowcaseView.class.getDeclaredField("showcaseDrawer");
               showcaseDrawerField.setAccessible(true);
               Object showcaseDrawerObject = showcaseDrawerField.get(showcaseViewObject);

               Field innerRadiusField = null;
               try {
                   innerRadiusField = showcaseDrawerObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("innerRadius");
               } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               if (null != innerRadiusField) {
                   /**
                    * detected that the new showcase-drawer is used
                    */
                   innerRadiusField.setAccessible(true);

                   Field outerRadiusField = showcaseDrawerObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("outerRadius");
                   outerRadiusField.setAccessible(true);

                   float oldInnerRadius = (float) innerRadiusField.get(showcaseDrawerObject);
                   float oldOuterRadius = (float) outerRadiusField.get(showcaseDrawerObject);
                   float newOuterRadius = radius * (oldOuterRadius / oldInnerRadius);

                   innerRadiusField.set(showcaseDrawerObject, radius);
                   outerRadiusField.set(showcaseDrawerObject, newOuterRadius);
               } else {
                   /**
                    * detected that the old showcase-drawer is used (no outer radius)
                    */
                   Field showcaseRadiusField = showcaseDrawerObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("showcaseRadius");
                   showcaseRadiusField.setAccessible(true);
                   showcaseRadiusField.set(showcaseDrawerObject, radius);
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return showcaseViewBuilder;
       }
   ```